# Trying to get the point of RxJavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, rx-javafx

So right now I'm reading about RxJavaFX and stumbled upon the following example:

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox <String> ();
comboBox.getItems().setAll("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon");
JavaFxObservable.valuesOf(comboBox.valueProperty())
    .subscribe(v - > System.out.println(v + " was selected "));
```

Why would I use the example above instead of this?

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox <String> ();
comboBox.getItems().setAll("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon");
comboBox.setOnAction(ae -> System.out.println(comboBox.getValue()));
```

I can't see the benefit of using RxJavaFX here. What am I missing?

Comment: In the simple example you provided? No benefit. But [RxJavaFX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX), which is a JavaFX "bridge" to the greater [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) library, allows you to create large chains of operations; this includes transformations, thread communication, etc.

Comment: See also [*Differences from ReactFX*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX#differences-from-reactfx) regarding _asynchronous_ design.